# how i can print the variable as it not the value of the variable

Tags: php

In this code

```
<?php print "value of a is $a" ?>
```

I need to print this statement as it how?

Comment: Where are **this** code and **this** statement? Please update question. :-)

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. Are you trying to print `$a`, and not the `a` variable's value? Then use single quotes instead of double.

Answer (score 4):

use single quote if you don't want to print the value of variable

```
<? php print 'value of a is $a' ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP performs [*variable parsing*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in [double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double),

You can use [single quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

So depending on want you really want, you can do

```
print 'value of a is $a';
```

which literally print the string `'value of a is $a'` (which does not make much sense).

Or you can use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to print the variable **and** it's value:

```
print 'value of $a is ' . $a;
```

which will print `'value of $a is 42'` (if `$a = 42;`).

Answer (score 1):

You could either use single quotes or escape `$a` within double quotes with a `\`.

Either:

```
<?php print 'value of a is $a' ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php print "value of a is \$a" ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print `$a` and not the a variable's value, there are two ways:

1. Escape the `$`: `print "value of a is \$a";`
2. Use single quotes instead

Everything in single quotes, including $something and special chars (newline \n, Unicode chars \uxxxx) are treated literally.

```
print 'value of a is $a';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print `$a` and not the `a` variable's value, there are two ways:

**1.** Escape the `$`

```
<?php print "value of a is \$a"; ?>
```

**2.** Use single quotes instead

Everything in single quotes, including `$something` and special chars (newline `\n`, Unicode chars `\uxxxx`) are treated literally.

```
<?php print 'value of a is $a'; ?>
```

Comment: Except for escaped single quotes, `\'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the variable in the string you must use single quotes like so

```
<? php print 'value of a is $a' ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second example produces the same output as the OPs code which he does *not* want.

Answer (score 0):

Append with a dot, escape double-quoted strings with a backlash, or use single quotes and obviate the need for escaping.